# In flyway maven plugin auto_increment doesn't fill id column with autoincrement values

Tags: mysql, database-migration, flyway

I use flyway plugin to my database migrations and one of my migrations has this sql:

```
-- Inserts sequential number into `id`
ALTER TABLE `DEVICES` MODIFY `id` BIGINT(20) AUTO_INCREMENT;
-- we don't need the auto_increment anymore
ALTER TABLE `DEVICES` MODIFY `id` BIGINT(20) UNIQUE;
-- This simulates a sequence. Starts at max(id); next id will be max(id)+1.
CREATE TABLE `DEVICES_ID_SEQUENCE` (id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO `DEVICES_ID_SEQUENCE` (SELECT max(id) from `DEVICES`);
```

but flyway doesn't fill  the column id of table DEVICES on existing rows. However if I execute this sentences manually, the existing rows are filled.

There are some workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Flyway executes your statements as-is, without transforming them.

Make sure you are connecting against the correct instance. Also check the log to see if any failure occurred.

Comment: Where is the log ? If you mean console output I didn't see any error, and I verified I'm connecting against the correct instance.